# problem about pip on installing on python

Tags: python, windows, bash, pip, runtime-error

when i want to install something on python like pip3 it doesn't work

when i write:

```
pip install (example)
```

or

```
pip3.exe
```

it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

so what i gonna do?

- i have been installed python3.11 again when i get this error but still doesn't work..

Comment: does this help?
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, pip isn't automatically bundled with python, you have to install it yourself.

You can run: `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` to install pip.

Then, you can run: `python -m pip install x` to install module x.

To upgrade pip, run: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

If you want, the pip documentation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) lists a few other ways of doing this.

Comment: well, usually pip nowadays *is* bundled with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Check if python is added to environmental variables. If add the installation path to the environmental variables.

For me, the convenient way to uninstall and reinstall and check all the option which says add path to environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest stable version of Python, make sure "install PIP" module is checked when running the setup of downloaded python on [python.org/downloads/](https://python.org/downloads/).

Then type py -m pip --version, to check if installed.

Hope this helps